# Should I convert Centeralised web app to Multichain because it is free to use and more secure compare to webapp?

Tags: blockchain, private-blockchain, dapps

I am Web app developer and exploring the blockchain technology from few months.

I want to convert the live centralized WebApp to Decentralized Blockchain application.

I know there is a high cost of Inserting data in to blockchain and there is 15 GB of data I want to put into Blockchain.

I came across the Multichain and found that, we can use it if we want to create private blockchain and there is no cost apart from server on which data is stored.

1 - The webApp is not having any Financial Info but simple user Info and Images. So is it advisable to use Multichain here?

2 - Can normal user like users outside organization can update the data?

3 - What is the your advise Normal Blockchain or Multichain?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally huge data like images should not be stored on the blockchain. You can store a pointer to the location of the file off-chain as well as the hash of the file on chain. Then while reading the file, you can use the hash from on chain to verify whether the data was changed after it was inserted.